# Java Regex for username

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking for a regex in Java, `java.util.regex`,  to accept only letters `’`, `-`, and `.` and a range of Unicode characters such as umlauts, eszett, diacritic and other valid letters from European languages.
What I don't want is numbers, spaces like `“  ”` or `“   Tom”`, or special characters like `!”£$%` etc.

So far I'm finding it very confusing.

I started with this

```
[A-Za-z.\\s\\-\\.\\W]+$
```

And ended up with this:

```
[A-Za-z.\\s\\-\\.\\D[^!\"£$%\\^&*:;@#~,/?]]+$
```

Using the cavat to say none of the inner square brackets, according to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html)

Anyone have any suggestions for a new regex or reasons why the above isn't working?

Comment: Are you getting an error message, or is it just not matching. In both cases, give us more information what exactly happens.

Comment: One problem might be that you use `\\D`. Use `\\d` inside the negated character class instead. Also, you should add `^` to the beginning. Otherwise your regex will match if only the last character of your string is one of the allowed ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use: (?=.*[@#$%&\s]) - Return true when atleast one special character (from set) and also if username contain space.

you can add more special character as per your requirment. For Example:

```
String str = "k$shor";
String regex = "(?=.*[@#$%&\\s])";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
System.out.println(matcher.find()); => gives true
```

Answer (score 1):

For my answer, I want to use a simpler regex similar to yours: `[A-Z[^!]]+`, which means "At least once: (a character from A to Z) or (a character that is not '!').
Note that *"not '!'"* already includes A to Z. So everything in the outer character group(`[A-Z...`) is pointless.

Try `[\p{Alpha}'-.]+` and compile the regex with the `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` flag.